Problem with: "Invalid key supplied", exception: "LogicException" (Laravel v10.26.2)
I had a problem, when I deploy my project into Heroku I try to register but this error comes out I try all solving I search for but doesn't help me, I use php artisan:migrate,  php artisan passport:keys and php artisan passport:install --force, but no one help :(
{message: "Invalid key supplied", exception: "LogicException",…}
exception: "LogicException"
file: "/app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php"
line: 67
message: "Invalid key supplied"

public function __construct($keyPath, $passPhrase = null, $keyPermissionsCheck = true)
    {
        $this->passPhrase = $passPhrase;

        if (\strpos($keyPath, self::FILE_PREFIX) !== 0 && $this->isValidKey($keyPath, $this->passPhrase ?? '')) {
            $this->keyContents = $keyPath;
            $this->keyPath = '';
            // There's no file, so no need for permission check.
            $keyPermissionsCheck = false;
        } elseif (\is_file($keyPath)) {
            if (\strpos($keyPath, self::FILE_PREFIX) !== 0) {
                $keyPath = self::FILE_PREFIX . $keyPath;
            }

            if (!\is_readable($keyPath)) {
                throw new LogicException(\sprintf('Key path "%s" does not exist or is not readable', $keyPath));
            }
            $this->keyContents = \file_get_contents($keyPath);
            $this->keyPath = $keyPath;
            if (!$this->isValidKey($this->keyContents, $this->passPhrase ?? '')) {
                throw new LogicException('Unable to read key from file ' . $keyPath);
            }
        } else { // ***** line 67 *****
            throw new LogicException('Invalid key supplied');
        }

        if ($keyPermissionsCheck === true) {
            // Verify the permissions of the key
            $keyPathPerms = \decoct(\fileperms($this->keyPath) & 0777);
            if (\in_array($keyPathPerms, ['400', '440', '600', '640', '660'], true) === false) {
                \trigger_error(
                    \sprintf(
                        'Key file "%s" permissions are not correct, recommend changing to 600 or 660 instead of %s',
                        $this->keyPath,
                        $keyPathPerms
                    ),
                    E_USER_NOTICE
                );
            }
        }
    }

I want to find what's is the problem because I try to solve it for a week

finally I find the solution add this in .env
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key here>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
 
PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<public key here>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

just write your key to be like this
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"


try php artisan key:generate

Try run
php artisan passport:keys


I try it but still not help

I finally find the solution add this in .env
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key here>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
 
PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<public key here>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

just write your key to be like this
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"


In my case I removed POSSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY and PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY from .env and its working or you can add directly there.

